# Java 8 to 11 migration - URL resolving does not work anymore

Tags: java, tomcat, java-11

I am migrating a large project that contains several Servlets
from Oracle JDK8 to OpenJDK11.
For some reason,
the REST calls used within the migrating Servlets
no longer work.
I created a simple Servlet to test whether or not
my application can reach any URL.
Here is the code of that test:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection =
  (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseCode());
```

Tomcat 9 is my application server.
When Tomcat runs with OpenJDK11,
the above code throws me following exception:
`java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`.
When Tomcat runs with JDK8,
everything works as excepted.
Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Which operating system is this and does the connect to google.com need to go through a proxy server?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 for testing. A proxy is configured but it is not needed to connect to google.com, but only for other internal urls.

Comment: To double check whether the proxy is the culprit you could try two things:
1.) try with `.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);` and see if that changes anything.
or 2.) try to set `ProxySelector.setDefault(ProxySelector.getDefault());`
Although arguably both should behave the same with jdk8 and jdk11.

Comment: Its funny, but with `openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY)` it works. So I deleted that proxy setting from setenv file. I have to check whether I need that proxy setting at all.